# Is there a word for the circumstance that the new thing/iteration is always the best?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example would be a computer. A computer that is build from the best parts in 2020 is better than one being build in 2010 and so on. Is there a term that describes this phenomenon?

Edit: Sorry for the poor wording. I don't know if I can word it clearer because I don't have the word for it (which is why I'm asking :D ) but I'll try.

Let's say you have an apple. This apple may be better or worse, depending on what you deem a good apple to be (more/less nutrients, more/less chemicals, etc.). So it's subjective whether an apple right now is better or worse than one you bought a year ago.

With a computer (sorry that I can't think of another example) the progress/advancement is not really subjective. If we define computer as a device that (stores and) processes data then a computer that has more computing capacity is strictly, objectively a better computer than one that has less computing capacity.

I wondered if there is a word that describes this phenomenon, that there are areas or things in areas in which a more developed state of a product or thing is strictly, objectively better.

Hope this helps a bit..

Comment: Do you mean apart from progress?

Comment: Latest and greatest?

Comment: Evolution, Improvement, Progress, Advancement, Development. Do any of these seem right?

Comment: Kadarin: All three of the preceding comments assume you're asking for a word to describe *the end result* of "new" things coming into existence ***if we take it as a given that "the new thing/iteration is always the best"***. My answer assumes that what you're asking for is how to describe the ***belief*** that the new thing/iteration ***really is*** always the best (which not everyone thinks is true - it's a ***belief / attitude***, not a ***fact***). Please edit the question to clarify which of those two possibilities is what you're asking about.

Comment: Are you asking for a name for the phenomenon that newer is better, or a name for the *belief* that newer is better?

Comment: Edited the question. Thank you all for taking time and thinking about this!

Comment: Not a single word, but the "March of Progress" alludes to the notion that newer is better. Ironically, the phrase comes from the domain of evolutionary history where the principle doesn't even apply.

Comment: Nol on the expression: the latest version is always the best

Comment: I'll probably have to settle with an idiom like "the latest ist always the best" or "latest and greatest"

Comment: Define "objectively better". To my mind, the only thing that comes close is evolution (as per @NuclearHoagie's comment). But even there, "better" is a temporary state of affairs. Giant dragonflies once thrived on Earth, and by any rational standards they must have been "better" than their predecessors (and their prey! :) But they couldn't live with the much lower oxygen content of today's air, so at some point in their evolutionary history, they must have switched from "getting better" to "getting worse / dying out / going extinct"

Comment: "With a computer (sorry that I can't think of another example) the progress/advancement is not really subjective. If we define computer as a device that (stores and) processes data then a computer that has more computing capacity is strictly, objectively a better computer than one that has less computing capacity." There's a difference between having better specifications and being better to use. Similarly the fastest car isn't necessarily the best to drive, and the strongest alcohol isn't the best to drink. I'm sure there's a term for constantly-increasing specifications but can't think.

Answer (score 1):

> [**neophilia**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophilia)  <sup><sub>(Merriam-Webster)</sub></sup>
> love of or enthusiasm for what is new or novel

*The earliest known example of neophilia in print is from an 1899 issue of Political Science Quarterly, a publication of Columbia University. The word is a combination of the Greek-derived combining forms neo-, meaning "new," and -philia, meaning "liking for." In the 1930s, the form neophily was introduced as a synonym of neophilia, but no neophilia could save it from obscurity-it has never caught on. The opposite of neophilia is neophobia, meaning "a dread of or aversion to novelty." It has been around slightly longer than neophilia, having first appeared in 1886.*

Comment: This describes an attitude, not the observable phenomenon (progress).

Comment: I don't see that. OP isn't trying to name "the observable phenomenon" - which to those people who *have* the attitude he's asking about, could indeed be called "progress". Not everyone believes that new is always better - in reality, "the observable phenomenon" is just that ***things change over time***. Which to people who manifest the attitude neophilia means we make ***progress*** as we move from Past to Future - but to someone with "neophobia", the observable phenomenon might more accurately be called ***decay, recidivism, regresssion,...***

Comment: The question clearly says "name for this phenomenon". It doesn't ask for a name for the belief/opinion that the phenomon is true.

Comment: @Barmar: You're assuming the OP has perfect command of English, in which case the question would be utterly pointless / trivial, so I can't really see why anyone would ask it. I assume the OP isn't very fluent in English, and either has a somewhat hazy idea of what exactly ***circumstance*** means, OR (more likely, imho) has missed a crucial element in the text - for example *...the new thing/iteration is always **assumed to be** the best*. But if OP doesn't respond to my request for clarification on that point, I will delete the answer and vote to delete the question as well.

Comment: Of course, we could ask them, and I've just done so.

Comment: Maybe your latest comment under the question is "better" than mine because it's *briefer* (now that at least *we* know what we're talking about! :), but I can't see you're asking anything *different.*